# Printing collision in python chat app

Tags: python, printing

I am successfully receiving real-time messages via socket.io server.
However, whenever message is received when I write my own message, there is a collision in terminal.

In my opinion, I need something like this:

"If message is received, cut prompt line (including unfinished text), print message, paste cut text"

Is it possible to implement this? Or any other best practices?

Here is my code:

```
import thread
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace

def on_response(*args):
    if type(args[0]) != str:
        print "\033[92m\033[1m" + args[0]["name"] + "\033[0m:", args[0]["text"]

with SocketIO('https://mede-chat-app.herokuapp.com/socket.io/', 443, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:
    socketIO.emit('joinRoom', {
        "name": "Sasha",
        "room": "Example"
    })
    socketIO.on('message', on_response)
    thread.start_new_thread(socketIO.wait, ())
    while True:
        msg = raw_input()
        socketIO.emit('message', {"name": "Sasha", "text": msg})
        print "\033[A                             \033[A"
```

Comment: It's not clear what sort of collision you're describing.  But it seems like you should use some kind of locking mechanism.  See https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#using-locks-conditions-and-semaphores-in-the-with-statement

Comment: this is example output:  r00t: Connected ;)\n Sasha: hello\n                               
I received msg when I writing thSasha: For example \n